# How to install Symfony 1.4.18 on Ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I have a project written with `Symfony 1.4.18` (Very old version) and now I need to install symfony library and packages on `Ubuntu 20.04`.

I copied all `symfony 1.4.18` files and libraries in Ubuntu but as I knew , it didn't work !

Answer (score 0):

You need to run old  php version < 5.6 , and the same apache modules tha were in orginal.

You writeing about copying  files - but  what about  databases ?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  Can you elaborate a bit more on your solution?